# Erro de renderização com router do angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routes

Estou estudando angular 2 e me deparei com um problema na aplicação que estou fazendo como estudo. Resolvi criar um CoreModule e nele criar um componente SideBar(menu) com os links para navegação da aplicação, entretanto não funcionou como esperado.

O sidebar é renderizado mas nos links ficam faltando renderizar o href, o que impossibilita a navegação:

```
<a _ngcontent-aap-3="" routerlink="/dashboard" routerlinkactive="active">Dashboard</a>
```

Vou deixar meu código a seguir, alguém saberia me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

app/core/sidebar/sidebar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

app/core/sidebar/sidebar.component.html

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/clientes" routerLinkActive="active">Clientes</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

app/core/core.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';

import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  exports: [SidebarComponent],
  declarations: [SidebarComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class CoreModule {
  constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error(
        'CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
    }
  }
}
```

app/app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

app/app.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
        <div class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 main">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app/app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/dashboard',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: '**',
                redirectTo: '/dashboard',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Tente importar o router nele, pode ser que ele não reconhece as diretivas.

Comment: Já tentei, tentei também criar um module para ele mas não deu certo.

Comment: Bom se estiver aparecendo a sidebar bonitinho na tela e não funcionar pode ser problema de encapsulamento, algo com o shadow dom. Sugiro ir pelo jeito mais fácil jogar o side bar e o router-outlet em um componente main.

Comment: Cria um plunker  com o código atual. Ta faltando path para clientes e olha direito esse pathMatch: 'full' até agora não precisei usar isso ai. Se te interessar eu preferi usar ui-router-ng2 do que o router do angular 2

Comment: Criei um plunker, segue o link: https://plnkr.co/edit/cfu3fu0SRxdTjWOJ624A?p=preview